# Azure terraform web app not getting listed in eclipse deployment option

Tags: java, azure, terraform

Case 1: I created a web app via azure portal (Java as application stack) and the web app is getting listed in the eclipse azure tool to build and deploy the jar.

Case 2: I created another web app under same app service plan with different name via Terraform and It's not getting listed in the eclipse azure tool.

After deployment I compared the json view of the two web application and everything is same, except name and timestamps ofcourse.

Below is site_config I used in terraform to make sure I get Java as application stack.

```
site_config {
       always_on = false
        
       application_stack {
         java_version = "jre8"
         java_server = "JAVA"
         java_server_version = "8"
       }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what I did, I simply clicked on the 'deployment center' option in the portal ,it took some time to display the ftp credentials and after that I was able to see the webapp as an option to deploy in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Generally due to some network glitch you might have not seen that option in eclipse.

You can try the below workarounds to see that option in eclipse to build and deploy:

1. Restart the eclipse and try again.
2. Try to restart the web app which was deployed using the terraform in the azure portal